# What causes "fatal: The remote end hung up unxepctedly" when using git to try and clone a repository on github?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone the facebook iOS API located on github.com. I'm new to git and I've just downloaded the git client. I also have created a github account. I thought I configured everything correctly but I'm running into the following error:

---

git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios.sdk.git

Cloning into facebook-ios.sdk...

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

---

Any help is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. Use this:

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even notice, I have no idea how that got in there I did a copy/paste. Thanks! :)